# How to return error object in in a HTTP API Future request

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am using BLOC Pattern, so my query is how to return some error post HTTP request.
Suppose if the API returns 200 as a status code I can return the particular model which I have mentioned if there is an error returning from the API like 302, 404 401... so on so how to handle this and return UI to show the error message

```
Future<SampleModel> getSomeDetails(String ID) async {
    var response =
    await http.get(someURL,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return SampleModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');// return the error to UI
    }
  }
```

PS: I am also using the observer Pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return:

```
Future.error("Error message").
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
getSomeDetails("id")
    .then((value) => print('Value: $value'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Error: $error'));
```

or

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getSomeDetails("id"),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text('Value: ${snapshot.data}');
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return Text('Loading...');
  },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using bloc, you probably have some kind of stream that you add data to:

```dart
StreamController<int> data = new StreamController<int>();
```

And you probably use StreamBuilder to listen for events on that stream and show the data. You can also listen for the errors on the stream:

```dart
StreamBuilder<int>(
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Show error message
      return Text('An error occured');
    } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // Show data
      return Text('${snapshot.data}');
    }

    // No data, show loader
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
  stream: data.stream,
),
```

So you can just an error to the stream:

```dart
// Adding an error to the stream
data.addError('Failed to load post');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using my own API call mechanism Which is given below in that you can manage all type of exceptions.

api_handler.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:package_name/base/api/api_exception.dart';
import 'package:package_name/utils/app_constatns.dart';
import 'package:package_name/utils/log_utils.dart';
import 'package:package_name/utils/preference_utils.dart';
import 'package:package_name/utils/strings.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiHandler {
  // next three lines makes this class a Singleton
  static ApiHandler _instance = new ApiHandler.internal();
  final JsonDecoder _decoder = new JsonDecoder();

  ApiHandler.internal();

  factory ApiHandler() => _instance;

  Future<bool> isInternetConnected() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
        connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<dynamic> get(String url) async {
    LogUtils.d("====URL GET Call:   $url");
    String token = PreferenceUtils.getString(AppConstants.LOGGED_IN);

    // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
    var isConnected = await isInternetConnected();
    if (isConnected != true) {
      return Future.error(ApiException(Strings.internetNotConnected));
    }
    return http.get(url, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"}).then(
        (http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      LogUtils.d("====response ${response.body.toString()}");

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 400 || json == null) {
        throw new ApiException(jsonDecode(response.body)["message"]);
      }
      return _decoder.convert(response.body);
    });
  }

  Future<dynamic> post(String url, {body, encoding}) async {
    LogUtils.d("====URL POST Call:   $url");
    LogUtils.d("====body :   $body");
    String token = PreferenceUtils.getString(AppConstants.LOGGED_IN);
    var isConnected = await isInternetConnected();
    if (isConnected != true) {
      return Future.error(ApiException(Strings.internetNotConnected));
    }

    return http.post(url,
            body: json.encode(body),
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              "Authorization": "Bearer $token"},
            encoding: encoding)
            .then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
      LogUtils.d("====responseBody ${response.body.toString()}");
      LogUtils.d("====responseStatusCode ${response.statusCode}");

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 400 || json == null) {
        throw new ApiException(jsonDecode(response.body)["message"]);
      }
      return _decoder.convert(response.body);
    });
  }
}
```

api_exception.dart

```
class ApiException implements Exception {
  String errorMsg = "Server not respond";

  ApiException(String error) {
    this.errorMsg = error ?? "Server not respond";
  }
}
```

api_manager.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter_my_recipes/utils/log_utils.dart';
import 'package:flutter_my_recipes/utils/preference_utils.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

import 'api_handler.dart';

class ApiManager {
  // next three lines makes this class a Singleton
  static ApiManager _instance = new ApiManager.internal();

  ApiManager.internal();

  factory ApiManager() => _instance;

  static ApiHandler _handler;

  static void init() {
    _handler = new ApiHandler();
  }

  static Future<LoginRes> loginApi(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return _handler.post(UrlConstants.LOGIN_URL, body: json).then((res) {
      return LoginRes.fromJson(res);
    });
  }
}
```

API call example :-

```
void loginApiCall(BuildContext context, LoginReq _signInReq) {
    ApiManager.loginApi(_signInReq.toJson()).then((signInResponse) {
      notifyListeners();
      print("===Success $signInResponse");
      PreferenceUtils.setString(
          AppConstants.USERDATA, JsonCodec().encode(signInResponse.toJson()));
      PreferenceUtils.setString(AppConstants.LOGGED_IN, signInResponse.token);
      isLoading = false;
      Navigation.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, Screens.HOME);
    }).catchError((onError) {
      isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
      print("===onError $onError");
      ProcessDialog.closeLoadingDialog();
      Toast.show(onError.errorMsg, context, duration: 2);
    });
  }
```

You have to call ApiManager init method in main.dart file so you can use Apimanager Instance allover the app.

Answer (score 0):

In the BLoC pattern, you can handle errors by emitting different states to indicate the success or failure of an operation. To return error messages to the UI, you can create a custom error state in your BLoC and emit it when an error occurs. Here's how you can modify your getSomeDetails function and BLoC to handle errors:

1:Create a custom error state in your BLoC

...
abstract class SomeDetailsState {}

```
class SomeDetailsLoadedState extends SomeDetailsState {
  final SampleModel sampleModel;

  SomeDetailsLoadedState(this.sampleModel);
}

class SomeDetailsErrorState extends SomeDetailsState.
  final String error;

  SomeDetailsErrorState(this.error);
}
```

2:Modify your BLoC to handle the HTTP request and emit the appropriate states

'''Dart
class SomeDetailsBloc {
final _someDetailsController = StreamControllerSomeDetailsState>();

```
StreamSomeDetailsState> get someDetailsStream => 
_someDetailsController.stream;

void getSomeDetails(String ID) async {
try {
var response = await http.get(someURL);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
final sampleModel = 
SampleModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

_someDetailsController.sink.add(SomeDetailsLoadedState(sampleModel));
} else {
_someDetailsController.sink.add(SomeDetailsErrorState('Failed to 
load data'));
}
} catch (e) {
_someDetailsController.sink.add(SomeDetailsErrorState('An error 
occurred'));
}
}

void dispose() {
_someDetailsController.close();
  }
}
```

3: In your UI, listen to the BLoC's stream of states and update the UI accordingly

```
    SomeDetailsBloc _bloc = SomeDetailsBloc();



    StreamBuilder<SomeDetailsState>(
    stream: _bloc.someDetailsStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data is SomeDetailsLoadedState) {
   final data = (snapshot.data as SomeDetailsLoadedState).sampleModel;
        // Render UI with the loaded data
      } else if (snapshot.data is SomeDetailsErrorState) {
   final error = (snapshot.data as SomeDetailsErrorState).error;
        return Text('Error: $error');
      }
    }
    // Render a loading indicator or initial state
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
   )
```